# Oracle SQL: Least Amount of Groupings up to amount

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

Suppose I have the following dataset named "Num":

```
80
70
50
40
20
20
20
10
```

I would like to add these numbers up into the least number of groupings that are less than (or equal to) 100.  Each number can be used only once.  So for the example above we would group as follows:

```
Group 1: 80 + 20
Group 2: 70 + 20 + 10
Group 3: 50 + 40
Group 4: 20
```

And my answer would be 4 (4 unique groupings as close to & including 100).

Comment: Are you looking for a pure SQL solution?  Solved in general, or for this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    num AS
        (
            SELECT 80 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 70 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 50 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 40 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 20 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 20 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 20 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT 10 "NUMBERS" FROM DUAL
        ),
    grid AS
        (   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NUMBERS DESC) "ID", NUMBERS "NUM" FROM num    ),
    add_0 AS
        (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY g0.ID ASC, g1.ID DESC, g2.ID DESC) "INDX",
                g0.ID "ID0",
                g0.NUM "NUM0", 
                
                g1.ID "ID1",
                g1.NUM "NUM1",
                g0.NUM + g1.NUM "RESULT0",
                
                g2.ID "ID2",
                g2.NUM "NUM2",
                g0.NUM + g1.NUM + g2.NUM "RESULT1"
            FROM
                grid g0
            INNER JOIN
                grid g1 ON(g1.ID > g0.ID)
            INNER JOIN
                grid g2 ON(g2.ID > g0.ID) 
            WHERE 
                g0.NUM + g1.NUM <= 100 OR
                g0.NUM + g1.NUM + g2.NUM <= 100
            ORDER BY g0.ID, g1.ID, g2.ID
        ),
    calc AS
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID0 ORDER BY ID0, ID1, ID2) "ORD",
                ID0, 
                CASE WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN 0 ELSE ID1 END "ID1", 
                CASE
                    WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN 0
                    WHEN CASE WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN RESULT1 <= 100 THEN RESULT1 ELSE 0 END END < 
                    CASE 
                      WHEN CASE WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN RESULT1 <= 100 THEN RESULT1 ELSE 0 END END > RESULT0 THEN 0
                    ELSE
                      RESULT0
                    END THEN 0
                ELSE 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN 0
                        WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 
                        WHEN RESULT1 = 100 THEN ID2
                        WHEN RESULT0 > RESULT1 THEN 0
                        WHEN RESULT0 <= RESULT1 THEN ID2
                    ELSE
                        Nvl(ID2,0)
                    END 
                END "ID2", 
              --
                NUM0, 
                CASE WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN 0 ELSE NUM1 END "NUM1", 
                CASE
                    WHEN CASE WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN RESULT1 <= 100 THEN RESULT1 ELSE 0 END END < 
                    CASE 
                      WHEN CASE WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN RESULT1 <= 100 THEN RESULT1 ELSE 0 END END > RESULT0 THEN 0
                    ELSE
                      RESULT0
                    END THEN 0
                ELSE      
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN 0
                        WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 
                        WHEN RESULT1 = 100 THEN NUM2
                        WHEN RESULT0 > RESULT1 THEN 0
                        WHEN RESULT0 <= RESULT1 THEN NUM2
                    ELSE
                        Nvl(NUM2,0)
                    END 
                END "NUM2",
              --
                CASE 
                  WHEN CASE WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 ELSE CASE  WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN 0 WHEN RESULT1 <= 100 THEN RESULT1 ELSE 0 END END > RESULT0 THEN 0
                ELSE
                  RESULT0
                END "RESULT0",
                CASE WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 ELSE CASE  WHEN ID1 = ID2 THEN 0 WHEN RESULT1 <= 100 THEN RESULT1 ELSE 0 END END "RESULT1"
            FROM
                add_0 a
            WHERE
                ID1 <> ID2
            ORDER BY 
                ID0, ID1,
                CASE 
                    WHEN RESULT0 = 100 THEN 0 
                    WHEN RESULT1 = 100 THEN ID2
                    WHEN RESULT0 > RESULT1 THEN 0
                    WHEN RESULT0 <= RESULT1 THEN ID2
                ELSE
                    Nvl(ID2,0)
                END,
                ORD
        ),
    a1 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ID0 "ID0", ID1 "ID1", ID2 "ID2", 
            NUM0 "NUM0", NUM1 "NUM1", NUM2 "NUM2", RESULT0 + RESULT1 "RESULT" 
        FROM 
            calc 
        WHERE 
            ROWNUM = 1
    ),
    a2 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ID0 "ID0", ID1 "ID1", ID2 "ID2", 
            NUM0 "NUM0", NUM1 "NUM1", NUM2 "NUM2", RESULT0 + RESULT1 "RESULT" 
        FROM 
            calc 
        WHERE 
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a1), ID0) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a1), ID1) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a1), ID2) = 0 And 
            RESULT0 + RESULT1 = (SELECT Max(RESULT0+RESULT1) From calc WHERE ID0 = 2) And
            ROWNUM = 1
    ),
    a3 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ID0 "ID0", ID1 "ID1", ID2 "ID2", 
            NUM0 "NUM0", NUM1 "NUM1", NUM2 "NUM2", RESULT0 + RESULT1 "RESULT" 
        FROM 
            calc 
        WHERE 
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a1), ID0) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a1), ID1) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a1), ID2) = 0 And 
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a2), ID0) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a2), ID1) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a2), ID2) = 0 And 
            ROWNUM = 1 
    ),
    a4 AS
    (
        SELECT 
            grid.ID "ID0", 0 "ID1", 0 "ID2",
            grid.NUM "NUM0", 0 "NUM1", 0 "NUM2", grid.NUM "RESULT" 
        FROM 
            grid 
        LEFT JOIN
            calc ON(grid.ID = calc.ID0)
        WHERE
            calc.ID0 Is Null And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a1), grid.ID) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a2), grid.ID) = 0 And
            InStr((SELECT ID0 || ID1 || REPLACE(ID2, 0, '') FROM a3), grid.ID) = 0 
    )
--  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
    GRP "GRP",
    CASE
        WHEN ID1 + ID2 = 0 THEN To_Char(NUM0)
        WHEN ID2 = 0 And ID1 <> 0 THEN  To_Char(NUM0) || ' + ' || To_Char(NUM1) 
        WHEN ID2 <> 0 THEN To_Char(NUM0) || ' + ' || To_Char(NUM1)  || ' + ' || To_Char(NUM2)
    END "MATH",
    RESULT "RESULT"
FROM
    (
            SELECT a1.*, 'Group: 1' "GRP" FROM a1
        UNION
            SELECT a2.*, 'Group: 2' "GRP" FROM a2
        UNION
            SELECT a3.*, 'Group: 3' "GRP" FROM a3
        UNION
            SELECT a4.*, 'Group: 4' "GRP" FROM a4
    )
```